# Prove by the definition $\lim\limits_{z \rightarrow 1}(\frac{z}{z+1})=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove by the definition $\;\lim\limits_{z \rightarrow 1}\left(\cfrac{z}{z+1}\right)=\cfrac{1}{2}$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Let $\epsilon >0 $ then $$\left|\frac{z}{z+1}-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\frac{|z-1|}{2|z+1|}$$

How can I bounded $\cfrac{1}{|z+1|}$ because if I take $|z-1| < c,$ $c >0$ then $|z+1|=|z-1 +2|< |z-1|+2 < c+2$ but $\cfrac{1}{c+1} < \cfrac{1}{|z+1|}$

Answer (score 2):

For $|c|<1$,$$|z-1|<c\implies|z+1|\ge2-|z-1|>2-c\implies\tfrac{1}{|z+1|}<\tfrac{1}{2-c}<\tfrac{1}{2-1}=1.$$